# Remove stop GIF animation function from ESC button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, gif, simplemodal

I want to remove stop GIF animation function from ESC button is it possible?

Please see this : http://jsfiddle.net/f8emy/

Press Upload then hit ESC once then press upload again and you'll notice the GIF animation stop moving.

Now i know you're gonna ask me why did i disable the SimpleModal internal ESC function:

```
escClose: false
```

and added another ESC function:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            $.modal.close();
        }
    });
});
```

is it because this way it will also cancel the page from loading instead of just closing the SimpleModal so that it will cancel the upload also.

What i want exactly is when you click upload the simplemodal will appear with the GIF and then if you pressed ESC it will close the simplemodal and cancel the uplaod (stop page from loading) then if you press upload again it will be the same with the GIF animation still playing inside the simplemodal. Thanks

Comment: Is the fiddle supposed to do something? I got nothin'.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f8emy/ new jsfiddle, sorry it did not include the simplemodal scirpt propely

Comment: What browser? the animation keeps going in Chrome.

Comment: The issue is "and cancel the uplaod". Unless you're using a 3rd party upload script, I don't think you can cancel a file upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is job for everyone's favorite Super Hero:[`preventDeafult()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault)-man!

```
// Close SimpleModal & Cancel Page Loading (from uploading)
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent browser from stopping animation
            $.modal.close();
        }
    });
});
```

Updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8emy/1/).

Firefox will stop gif animations when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed; `e.preventDefault()` will prevent this action, and keep the party, erm...gif animation, going.

Comment: This works but now it will not stop the page from loading to cancel the file upload... I need to not cancel the GIF animation but just the page loading and SimpleModal

Comment: If you are relying on the user to have his keys bound to a certain action (like stopping page load) I feel bad for you son. You got 99 problems, and the user is one. You should be doing the upload via ajax, and just abort the request if needed.